# Convergence of $A=\{a,2,2,2,...\}$ for $a\in\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Consider a sequence $A$, such that the first time is $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ and each following number is $2$, i.e. $A=\{a,2,2,2,...\}.$ Is it obvious that the sequence $A$ converges to $2$? Or is there more subtle limit here.

For instance, as $a\in\mathbb{Q}$, it can clearly take the value of any rational number. Then could the set $B=\{100,2,2,2,...\}$ be considered to converge to $2$?

Comment: Yes, it obviously converges to $2$.  To see this, use the $\epsilon$-$N$ definition of what it means to converge to a limit... and note that $N=2$ suffices for every choice of $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks, I will prove this by the $\epsilon-N$ definition to support my intuition.

Comment: "Is it obvious that the sequence A converges to 2?" Yes.  "Or is there more subtle limit here." No.  "Then could the set B={100,2,2,2,...} be considered to converge to 2?"  Of course it does.  why would the $100$ have anything to do with the limit?

Comment: Sets have no order and do not converge.  Sequences have order, are written with parentheses, and can converge to something.  Any sequence that is eventually constant converges to the constant value.  It does not matter that $a$ is rational.

Comment: Well, changing any finite number of terms in a sequence has no impact on its behavior as far convergence /divergence etc is concerned. So consider your statement as obvious. While introducing sequences and limits the textbook should discuss such obvious facts explicitly and not leave it for reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_1 = a$ and $a_i = 2$ for all $i\ge 2$.

For any $\epsilon > 0$ then for $n \ge N = 2$ we have $|a_n - 2| = |2-2|=0 < \epsilon$ so $\lim a_n = 2$ and no matter what possible.

Notice that what value $a$ is will never have *anything* to do with whether a sequence converges or not.

Indeed, this might be subtle, or it may be obvious,  *no* single term or finite set of terms in *any* sequence will determine whether a sequence converges or not.

The definition of $\lim a_n= k$ means that we can find a point where all the terms after that point are all close to $k$.  We can make them as close as we like be taking points further and further out.

So for any term, $a_m$, it doesn't matter how far away it is from $k$ as we can just take terms after $a_m$.